# Should I convert classification output to integer and how?

Tags: text-mining

I'm using a neural network to classify text, and the label of the training data is 0 or 1(i.e. binary classification). It works well in the training and evaluating process, but the prediction output is float values rather than integer 0 or 1. How could I always get integer results? Do i need to manually convert them or change network parameters?

```
model = Sequential()
e = Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, weights=[embedding_matrix], 
input_length=max_length, trainable=False)
model.add(e)
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# compile
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
print(model.summary())

# fit
model.fit(padded_docs, labels, epochs=5, verbose=2)

# eval
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(padded_docs, labels, verbose=0)
print('Accuracy: %f' % (accuracy*100))

# predict
result = model.predict(padded_docs_test, verbose=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Numerical predictions - which I assume are predicted probabilities - are *exactly* what a statistical method should output, for reasons given in [Classification probability threshold](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312119/1352).

I see that you are calculating accuracies. I recommend [Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352) and [Is accuracy an improper scoring rule in a binary classification setting?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/359909/1352)